# Optimize SQL Where Clause in Report Builder with Multiple Nested Filter Combinations

Tags: sql, optimization, parameters, where-clause, reportbuilder3.0

I am required to use Report Builder 3.0 to query a database. I've been tasked with looking up data for a list of individuals who had certain events within a date range. The trouble is that the date range will differ for each individual. I was able to generate a chain of AND/OR combinations that would give me the results I need, but it appears to be too complex as it is causing the query to time-out if I have more than 5,000 individuals (and the list I'm working from contains about 80,000 individuals).

To make things simple, let's say I'm working for a gym company, and management has asked for a membership and usage report. They give me the list of member numbers and the date range in which those members were active. They want to know activity details. So, I put together two queries. One gathers the desired details about each individual. The other identifies the records to be retrieved and passes the references over to the first query as a parameter. The date ranges will always be a matching pair, but they will all be different for each individual.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
  Member.Name
  ,Member.Address
  ,Visit.VisitDate
  ,Visit.ArrivalTime
  ,Visit.DepatureTime
  ,Visit.PersonalTrainerUsage
FROM
  Member
  INNER JOIN Visit
    ON Member.MemberID = Visit.MemberID
WHERE
  Member.MemberID IN (@MemberIDs)
  OR Visit.VisitID IN (@VisitIDs)
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT
  Member.MemberID
  Visit.VisitID
FROM
  Member
  INNER JOIN Visit
    ON Member.MemberID = Visit.MemberID
WHERE
  Member.MembershipState IN (WA, OR, CA, ID, NV, UT, AZ, NM)
  AND(
    (MemberID = 12345
    AND ((Member.StartDate >= 2021-01-05
        AND Member.StartDate <= 2023-05-31)
      OR (Visit.VisitDate >= 2021-01-05
        AND Visit.VisitDate <= 2023-05-31)))
    OR
    (MemberID = 23456
    AND ((Member.StartDate >= 2020-09-16
        AND Member.StartDate <= 2022-12-31)
      OR (Visit.VisitDate >= 2020-09-16
        AND Visit.VisitDate <= 2022-12-31)))
    OR
    (MemberID = 34567
    AND ((Member.StartDate >= 2019-02-14
        AND Member.StartDate <= 2023-01-31)
      OR (Visit.VisitDate >= 2021-02-14
        AND Visit.VisitDate <= 2023-01-31)))
)
```

There has got to be a more efficient way to do this, but I know just enough about SQL to make Report Builder cooperate most of the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create a table of member specific parameters and check if a row with matching memberId and parameters exists.

Comment: Just put your MemberIDs and their relevant date range in a separate table, or build a table constructor / derived table of values - and join to it.

Comment: @Stu I'm afraid I don't know how to do what you're describing. Can you point me to some instructions?